# Shuffling a sorted array

Tags: java, random, complexity-theory, big-o

If we are given an array that is sorted, what algorithm can we use to create an output array that has the same elements as the sorted array, but the elements should be randomly shuffled. I am looking for an algorithm that has a complexity of O(n)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Collections.shuffle(List)` has an `O(n)` time complexity.  You can use `Arrays.asList()` to wrap the array so you can use this function.

What it does is;

For each element from the last to the second element, swap the element with a random element from the rest of the list which includes itself i.e. it could randomly not move an element.

```
for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
    swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code

```
    // Create a list
    List list = new ArrayList();
    // Add elements to list
    // Shuffle the elements in the list
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    // Create an array
    String[] array = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    // Shuffle the elements in the array
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Count is: " + i + " letter is " + array[i]);
    }
```

This will print something like :

> Count is: 0 letter is b
>
> Count is: 1 letter is a
>
> Count is: 2 letter is c

from http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Shuffle.html